# UIView zoom effect on landscape mode

Tags: uiview, core-animation, zooming, landscape-portrait

My app has a subview displaying a graph. What I want to do it's to recreate a zoom effect (similar to the iPhone Stocks app) which will enlarge the graph view till filling up the whole screen in landscape mode as soon I tilt the device.

Just to be precise, I would like to rotate the subview and, after that, to send it in fullscreen meanwhile (this would be a plus) the other views fade out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Maybe looked at methods like `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`?

Comment: for intercepting the rotation I'm using
     
`NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];`
`[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) `
`name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`
             `object:device];`
`
My problem is to create the zoom effect for the subview. Check the Stocks app

Comment: For now I'm working with the first animation (the rotation) using 'CGAffineTransformRotate'. The zoom looks the more problematic since I'm not able to match the subview with the window in landscape mode.